# List cannot be displayed in Datasheet view

Tags: datasheet

I can't open my list in Data sheet view.

It throws me an error saying, can anyone help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Office 2010, 64-bit (with IE7 or IE8):

1. Ensure that your browser settings have the site in Trusted Sites in the Internet zone, and that ActiveX controls are enabled.
2. Install the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components.  I can confirm that this solution has worked for several of my colleagues.

Solution source:   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/e3eacc3d-d0da-41fb-bdeb-e524050820e6

MS Knowledgebase article:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2266203

If you are running Office 2007:

1. Ensure that your browser settings have the site in Trusted Sites in the Internet zone, and that ActiveX controls are enabled.
2. Ensure that the Microsoft Office Access Web Datasheet Component and the Windows SharePoint Service Support options for Microsoft Office are installed. (Steps here)

MS Knowledgebase article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909506/en-us

Reference link : http://amatterofdegree.typepad.com/a_matter_of_degree/2010/11/fix-for-datasheet-view-issue-error-in-sharepoint-2010.html